# Why doesn't this generic code which works for displaying a PDF in iOS, but not in Android?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

In the code below I write a PDF file out to the App Data Directory and open it in a Xamarin WebView.  This works fine in iOS but in Android nothing displays.  Why does this work in iOS but not Android?

I tried saving it to different locations like the CacheDirectory too.

```
   public DocumentViewer(JaxrsGetDocumentResults doc)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string directory = FileSystem.AppDataDirectory;
        var file = Path.Combine(directory, doc.FileName);

        if (!File.Exists(file))
        {
            File.WriteAllBytes(file, doc.FileBytes);
        }
        wv.Source = new Uri("file://" + file);

    }
```

I would think this would work the same in Android since Android can load PDF's in its web browser.  In other words I can open Chrome in the Android emulator and navigate to a PDF url and it loads.  See example below:

[image]

Comment: "Android can load PDF's in it's web browser [citation needed]".

Comment: I don't have a citation but if I open Chrome in the emulator that comes with Visual Studio and navigate to a PDF on the web it opens.

Comment: I don't believe this is universally true for all versions of Android, or for all device makers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WebView control can display PDF files on the iOS platform, but not on the Android and Windows Phone platforms due to lack of platform support. On the Android and Windows Phone platforms, Mozilla's pdf.js can be used to add this support. pdf.js is a JavaScript library for parsing and rendering PDFs using the HTML5 canvas element.

So on Android, you have to create a custom renderer and use like pdf.js to display the PDF in a Webview.

[Here](https://github.com/xamarin/docs-archive/tree/master/Recipes/xamarin-forms/Controls/display-pdf) is the official documentation and tutorial on how to achieve that.

Comment: Thanks this gets me farther but if I download the official tutorial and run it on the Android emulator the PDF is grayed out and not showing images.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer as it is the official answer - although I think it needs to be updated as it does not work fully on Android.

Comment: Hi Stephen, what problems are you getting?

Comment: When I download the sample and run it in the Android emulator the PDF is "grayed out" and the images do not show.

Comment: Are you loading from external source, or directly from the project?

Comment: My project is a local file I download.  But if I download the sample project and run it - it's grayed out and no graphics.  Does the sample project work for you?